# Using links (<a> tags) without changing the url in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular and UI-Router to build a website.

I have a menu sidebar on my page. some of the menu items have sub-menu items, so I am trying to implement collapse functionality to display the sub-menu item when user click on the parent menu item.

In my parent menu item, I have an  so when the user clicks on the menu link it should display the sub menu items. the problem is when the user clicks on the link it changes the url and redirects to the homepage.

A sample of my HTML is given to better understand.

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `#` from the `href` like so:

```
<li>
    <a href="">Menu Item 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Or alternatively, replace them with `span` tags and style them using `cursor: pointer`. I'm not sure which one is more semantically valid, but either will work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove href and replace with ng-href (angular href good practice)

```
<li>
    <a ng-href="/iwannago/tonexpage">Menu Item 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a ng-href="">link1</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="">link2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Using angular values is a Good Practice and Gets support Because ng-** keywods tags etc are from angular family

Comment: Doesn't make sense to have ng-href as we don't have any bindings on href attribute